# Upgrading an installation built using InstallShield

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, upgrade, installshield

I used free version of InstallShield, built in Visual Studio 2015 to build a setup for my app.
Now I want to release an upgrade version for my app, but after installing setup on target machine which has previous installed, I get this error :

`Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.`

[image]

I tried using upgrade code, but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it [im still very newb @ Installshield] the upgrade code should stay the same across the versions [service packs] but the product code should change with the version/service packs.

How to do it is described in the thread you can find in the comment from Michael Urman.